# Benefit of Defragging SQL Server Data files located on a SAN

Tags: sql-server, storage-area-network, defrag

In the past, I have used contig.exe to remove physical fragmentation from SQL Server data files. They have always been on locally attached storage. Is there any benefit to running this on a data file that is stored on a SAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recommended to defragment files on a SAN, SQL or otherwise.

See [this related ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/31011/sql-database-physical-file-fragmentation) and [this excellent whitepaper](http://www.las-solanas.com/storage_virtualization/san_volume_defragmentation.php). The major points include:

- Defragmenting is very I/O intensive
- Defragmenting doesn't always improve performance on logical volumes
- Defragmenting is definitely not recommended for certain specific configurations, like  Virtual Storage Pools and Replicated Volumes

Comment: Good pointers. I should have looked a little harder before posting thanks